# Spring block systems

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, spring

Why do we use energy conservation to obtain maximum displacement of the block in spring block system whereas for displacement of the mean position(equilibrium position) we use $F_{net} = 0$ on the block?

The below image describes the actual problem
[image: A block of mass 'm']

Comment: can you explain the question more clearly, are you asking about how to derive?

Comment: @MukunthA.G the question is that a mass m is connected to a spring of spring constant k and that the mass has a charge Q. It is kept in an electric field E . The question then asks what is the maximum displacement and the displacement of the equilibrium postion.

Comment: @MukunthA.G hold on I am trying to add an image of the question but its failing to add it.

Comment: you could just paste the link location of the image, no need to upload

Comment: @MukunthA.G https://images.app.goo.gl/rtm1RYTcMzAedLGH8

Comment: i am cooking an answer, i think you have a confusion on work energy theorem. Meanwhile i type an answer i would give you a hint. "If net force is zero, does a mass necessarily be at rest?"

Comment: @user270156 you can add images through the stack exchange website. It is not currently possible to do it through the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The block will remain at rest when the net force on it is zero is a flawed statement

Hence, $$qE - kx = 0$$  only gives the displacement when the net force on the block is zero.

$$x_{F_{net}=0} = \frac {qE}{k}$$

But, $\vec a_{net} = 0$ does'nt mean $\vec v = 0$, there is some velocity of the block which it carries and moves forward but once you have a displacement greater than $x_{F_{net}=0}$ the spring force becomes dominant and the body decelerates.

I am skipping the equations of motion for simple harmonic motion but the below graphs may help

[image: ...]

Note that at a time $\frac T4$, $\vec a = 0$ but $\vec v = max$. You can think of it like the body moves further because it has built up that much inertia.

Here comes the importance of work energy theorem, since it's hard to find the equations of motion, we use this theorem which states that,

> The net external work done on a body is equal to it's change in kinetic energy

In our case $\Delta K = 0$ starting from rest initialy and ending up at rest.

Hence,

$$W_{ext, net} = 0$$
$$W_{spring} + W_{Elec.} = 0$$
$$\int_0^D kx\,\text{d}x - \int_0^D qE\, \text dx = 0 $$

Solving it we get $$D_{block} = \frac {2F}{k}$$

Now you could compare the inital final states of spring, you could say that the mean position has displaced half the displacement of the block.

Another nice thing to mention here is that $kx = qE$ also gives you the same displacement for mean position but you are allowed to do it only after you solve the equations of motion for the block.

Comment: Note that the work done by electric force is negative because cos(180°) = -1

Comment: Also not that this is not an perfect simple harmonic because a constant external force acts on the body

Comment: thanks a lot I got it now

Comment: you could accept the answer if it really satisfied you, by clicking on that tick mark

Comment: I don't see any reference to electric charge in the original question.

Comment: you could see that in the subsequent comment

Comment: @MukunthA.GM when the spring is stretching is the work done by electric field still negative?

Comment: Oops! I switched the signs!

Answer (score 0):

The force exerted by a spring is determined by its displacement.  We use energy when we are given or are looking for a velocity. Referring to the diagram, at equilibrium, $qE = kx_o$.  At maximum, $qEx = \frac12kx^2$.

Comment: But that's not O.P's demand, the O.P is a new contributor hence i faired the question for him/her but it still needs to be approved

Comment: His original question asked about the difference between using force and energy.

Comment: exactly! but he had a peculiar case which i also had, [see here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/565889/contradictory-results-for-maximum-angular-displacement-using-different-approache) , hence he probably needed more facts which explain your statement.

Comment: what do you mean by equilibrium?

Comment: oh yes! thank you for pointing the difference between static and dynamic equilibrium...i thought equilibrium just meant static.